# Add a menu context to search specific strings.(How to use workbench.action.findInFiles?)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to add a menu context option to search specific query strings.
This query string is concatenated by constant string (with regex) and selected string.

For example :

The string = "HANDLE*"
When I select "EVENT" in editor and right click menu and click option.
It will jump to search viewlet and perform searching "HANDLE*EVENT" automatically.

According [#99575](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99575).
Here is my code in package.json:

```
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "testext.hello",
        "title": "HELLO"
      }
    ],
    "menus": {
      "editor/context": [
        {
          "when": "editorTextFocus",
          "command": "workbench.action.findInFiles",
          "args": {
            "query": "HANDLE*${selectedText}",
            "regexp": true
          },
          "group": "navigation"
        }
      ]
    }
```

The option has add to menu succesfully and click it will jump to search viewlet.
But query string has no pass to search viewlet.

I want to know How to pass the query string correctly?Thanks

Comment: you can't specify args in `package.json`, create a command in your extension and there call `workbench.action.findInFiles`

Comment: Should I use `vscode.commands.executeCommand('search.action.openEditor')` in extension.ts?How to pass "args" here?

Comment: where in the question do you mention `search.action.openEditor`, why do you want to open a search editor when you want to fill a few fields in the search bar

Comment: Oh sorry,I just want to the search specific string in files.  
`search.action.openEditor` could be an alternative.

Comment: I see the problem,use case of #99575 is only for `keybindings.json`.
Now I can perform searching with "args" by add a key shortcut.

Comment: Now my problem is :  
How to pass "args" to `vscode.commands.executeCommand()` when using `workbench.action.findInFiles` or `search.action.openEditor`.

Comment: what does the API page tell you about `executeCommand()`

Comment: [build-in commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands) mentioned it , but it doesn't describe available args.

Comment: is that the only API page you read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use build-in commands in `keybindings.json`:
It can add a key shortcut to search string with args.

```
    {
        "key": "alt+f",
        "command": "search.action.openEditor",
        "args": {
            "query":"${selectedText}",
            "isRegexp": true,
            "matchWholeWord":true
        }
    }
```

If want to trigger search command from menu should be following extension dev flow.
Call `executeCommand` with `openEditor` and args in `extension.ts`:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('search.action.openEditor',{
            query:"${selectedText}",
            matchWholeWord:true
        });
```

P.S. `workbench.action.findInFiles` has some problem with ${selectedText}.
I have reported it. [#173653](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173653)